# Blowing up a double cover at a ramified point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a projective variety which is a double cover, that is, there exists a finite map $\sigma: V \to Q$ of degree 2, ramified over a divisor $W \subset Q$. Suppose $x \in V$ is smooth (the case I'm looking at is when $x$ is an quadratic singularity, but I'd like to start off simple) and ramified, that is $\sigma(x) \in W$.

Let $\bar{V} $ be the blow up of $V$ at $x$. with exceptional divisor $E$. consider also $\bar{Q}$ the blow up of $Q$ at $\sigma(x)$ with exceptional divisor $\bar{E}$.

What is the relation between $E$ and $\bar{E}$? I'm told that $\sigma$ should induce a double cover $E \to \bar{E}$, but I'm not sure how to show it. In the smooth case at least, $E$ and $\bar{E}$ can be interpreted as the projectivised tangent bundles at $x$ and $\sigma(x)$ respectively, so then you just need to understand how $\sigma$ acts on these.

To be more specific, the example I'm looking at it where $Q$ is a smooth hypersurface of degree 3 in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$, and $W \subset Q$ is cut out from Q by a hypersurface of degree $2(n-2)$, so $V$ is a Fano variety of index $1$.

Bonus question: Is the double cover $E \to \bar{E}$ ramified or not?

Comment: May I suggest first, since the question is local, the map can be identified with the following. Consider $k[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]\subset k[[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},u]]$, where the map takes $x_i\mapsto x_i$ for $i<n$ and $x_n\mapsto u^2$. If you work this case out, rest should be clear.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, in this case the two blow ups are given by blow up along the ideals $(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ and $(x_1, \dotsc ,x_{n-1}, u^2)$ respectively. The exceptional divisors are given as $\bigoplus (x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ and $\bigoplus (x_1, \dotsc ,x_{n-1}, u^2)$, and the map takes one to the other in the same way.